# numeric keyboard resigns to normal key board in swift

Tags: swift, keyboard, numeric

I have a normal set up for a textfield with numberpad and the dismiss keyboard and resignFirstResponder actions in place, but when I tap on the background the numeric keyboard changes to the normal keyboard and then when I tap the background again the keyboard dismisses - STRANGE! How can I dismiss the numeric keyboard with one tap to the background?

```
self.textField.delegate = self
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad

 @IBAction func tapBackground(sender: AnyObject) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

@IBAction func viewTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
       textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following this may help you :)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapGesture:")
        tap.delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }
// MARK: - UITapGestureRecognizer
    func handleTapGesture(gesture : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool
 {
return true
 }
```